# list/modify Filters of log4j2 programatically

Tags: java, log4j2

This is my `log4j2.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyAppx" packages="">
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="Application" fileName="/var/log/flex/flextask-websocket.log" filePattern="/var/log/flex/archive/flextask-websocket-%d{yyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
        <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="debug"  onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            </Filters>
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} websocket  %-10level %class{36} %L %M - %msg%xEx%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="Application" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Now I want to modify Filters programatically

My code so far is

```
LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext)     LogManager.getContext(false);           
Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
LoggerConfig loggerConfig = config.getLoggerConfig(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
```

According to the structure of the xml file I would suspect to do

```
loggerConfig.getAppenders().get("Application").getFilters()
```

but the `getFilters()`  method is not available

I only can do

```
loggerConfig.getFilter()
```

which returns a single filter.
But how can I have access all filters? And where is the relation between filter and appender?

My goal is to filter only specific log levels at Runtime.

so when I say eg. `setFilter("Level1;Level2")`

I want to remove `allFilters` and filter only for Level1 and Level2

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this? I am working on a similar task and I need to list filters of an appender

Answer (score 1):

Techniically Log4j only supports a single filter. To allow multiple filters the filter will be a CompositeFilter that contains the other filters. If you only have a single filter just specify that without the filters element.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little ugly, but you can actually list all the filters of an appender by invoking `getFilter()` and by casting the returned filter to `CompositeFilter`:

```
final LoggerContext context =
            (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
final ConsoleAppender appender =
            context.getConfiguration().getAppender("Application");
final Filter rootFilter = appender.getFilter();

if (rootFilter instanceof CompositeFilter) {
    final CompositeFilter composite = (CompositeFilter)rootFilter;
    for (final Iterator<Filter> it = composite.iterator();
            it.hasNext(); ) {
        final Filter filter = it.next();
        // do something
    }
}
```

This is not part of the public API, so use with caution, but it seems that [Log4j2 actually does that internally](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/9abb6b00d25fb9c416b467fdb1dfe0293b76bf80/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/Logger.java#L280).